# Plotting number of times a name occurs in a column (histogram)

Tags: r, openoffice-calc

I have a list of names sorted, like below:

```
ACVR2B
ADAM19
ADAM29
ADAM29
ADAMTS1
ADAMTS1
ADAMTS1
ADAMTS12
ADAMTS16
ADAMTS16
ADAMTS16
ADAMTS17
ADAMTS17
ADAMTSL1
ADCY10
```

would like to plot them as a histogram. It is very easy when these are values but with characters how can I do it in R or in open office?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try plotting the result of `table()`.  The function `table()` computes the cross-tabulation frequency, which is exactly what you want.

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE)
plot(table(x))
```

[image]

---

To plot the sorted values, try this:

```
z <- sort(table(x))
plot(z, xaxt="n", type="h")
axis(1, at=seq_along(z), names(z))
```

[image]

Comment: can i also sort this plot that it plots only the top 10 high frequency elements?

Comment: Of course that won't work.  You need to sort the table.

Comment: I also did, plot(sort(table(x))), this works but I miss the names.

Comment: I added example of sorting and plotting the results

Answer (score 1):

Given to what Andrie suggested: I did this:

Letter<-read.table("letters", header=T)

```
x <- sample(Letters, replace = F)
plot(sort(table(x)))
```

but the things is when, I want to plot in a descending order with only top 10 I miss out on the labels.

Can anyone suggest how to fix it and get only top 10.